# read in list of urls from file then use pandas to make changes and output new csv file

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

I have this script that read in a list of csv's from a text file, the files are hosted online. The script then makes changes to each of the files and creates a new csv from the changes. At the moment it works for a single file by I cant get it to run through all the links and make new csvs files from each. 
import pandas as pd

```
f = open( "urls.txt", "r" )
lines = []
url = lines
for line in f:
   lines.append(line)
   df = pd.read_csv(url,skiprows=7)
   df = df.rename(columns={'*.conradbrothers.com/*_20180501':'Ranking','*.conradbrothers.com/*_difference': 'Difference'}) # Raname the top coloumn names
   df = df.replace(to_replace=["-"],value="0") #find - and replace with 0
   print(df)
   df.to_csv('seo.csv',index=False) #output file as a csv
   print(line)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the code, it seems like you are reading an empty list:

```
    df = pd.read_csv(url,skiprows=7)
```

wouldn't it be

```
    df = pd.read_csv(line,skiprows=7)
```

I am just guessing, the information provided in the question is limited

Oh an by the way, you are saving the csv each time with the same name, so you are overwriting it, consider changing the name in each iteration of the loop